# A finite non-abelian $p$-group contains at least an element of order $p^2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian $p$-group such that $G$ contains at least an element of order $p^2$ and for every nontrivial normal subgroup $N$, $G/N$ has not any elements of order $p^2$ and $G/Z(G)$ is non-abelian group.

1. Is there a group with these properties?
2. Are there up to p non-trivial proper subgroups such that intersection of every non-trivial proper subgroup of G with at least one subgroup of these p subgroups is non-trivial.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The condition on $G/G'$ is automatic from the property that proper quotients have no elements of order $p^2$.

Comment: Some background for this question? The easy examples of non-abelian finite $\;p\,-$ groups don't fulfill this ( $\;D_4,\,Q_8\;$), so you may have in mind something of higher, perhaps much higher, order...why, from where...?

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much. E.Stebbe

Comment: There are groups of order $81$ satisfying 1, such as $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(81,7)$. I don't know about 2, but you could check that yourself by computer.

Comment: do you consider a certain program for checking 2 by computater?

Comment: Yes you could use GAP, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I can use GAP somewhat. I mean do you know that I use from what algorithms or instructions.

Comment: Yes, but I am afraid that I do not provide help with using GAP. You could start off with G := SmallGroup(81,7);; Exponent(G); NilpotencyClassOfGroup(G); NS:=NormalSubgroups(G);;